# Not able to see my website and dashboard too

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, web-hosting, localserver

Today I tried to shift my local server website to the live server, and I had completed all the steps given in the internet including the changes done in siteurl and home of wp_options and made changes in wp-config file too. But still I am not able to see my site in interner and not even able to access the dashboard of wordpress. If I am trying to open my site i.e notesbank.in or trying to access the dashboard by notesbank.in/wp-admin , Then I can only see this page. 
www.notesbank.in

Answer (score 0):

it says"Error establishing a database connection" check wp-config file once